# Xpath select multiple classes

Tags: python, html, xpath, html-parsing, lxml

```
<div class="one">
    <a class="two" href="Something..."><img src="http://..."/></a>
    <p> stuff.... </p>
    <p><img src="http://....." /></p>
</div>
```

I have this silly HTML which I am parsing, as you can see there is one main class called *one* and another one nested called *two*.
I am trying to parse all the images in class *one*, but apparently the XPath I have is only catching one image, which is the image from class *one*

I tried this:

```
//div[@class="one"]/img | //a[@class="two"]/img
```

But apparently I am not catching from class *two*, but only from class *one* is there anyway to do this?

I am using lxml.html's xpath feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this `Xpath` expression :

```
//div[@class="one"]//img
```

Test :

```
xmllint --html --xpath '//div[@class="one"]//img' \
    'http://sputnick-area.net/ftp/downloads/testSO.html'
```

**OUTPUT**

```
<img src="http://...">
<img src="http://.....">
```

Comment: I have also tried this, but unfortunatly it keeps on getting one only :-(

Comment: Yes guys, it's working perfect, it was a mistake I have done when running the changed code! Thanks dudes!